# MySQL: SUM(column) always returns null when parsed with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, parsing, sum

I'm trying to retrieve a sum of a column and parse it with JSON.

To retrieve the sum I use:

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM `Fuelconsumption` WHERE `date` like '%09-2012%'
```

When I use this command into my SQL Server directly, i get a figure result, when I try to parse it through JSON it doesn't work.

Here is my JSON and PHP Code:

```
case 'getstats':

                    $query="SELECT SUM(price) FROM `Fuelconsumption` WHERE `date` like '%09-2012%'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);

                    $json = array();
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                                $json['price']=$row['price'];
                        }
                        print json_encode($json);
                    mysql_close();
    break;
```

And this is my JS:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var jsontext = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var json = JSON.parse(jsontext);



        console.log(jsontext)



    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "mysql.php?p=getstats" + "&date=09-2012", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Try changing the query to `SELECT SUM(price) AS sum_price` instead

Comment: Try the following query: `SELECT SUM(\`price\`) as \`price\` FROM \`Fuelconsumption\` WHERE \`date\` LIKE '%09-2012%'`.

Comment: I believe this is solved. However in future you could find out using `var_dump($json)`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$query="SELECT SUM(price) AS price FROM `Fuelconsumption` WHERE `date` like '%09-2012%'";
```

instead of

```
$query="SELECT SUM(price) FROM `Fuelconsumption` WHERE `date` like '%09-2012%'";
```

Also, why are you using normal Javascript to create Ajax requests instead of jQuery while your name is jQuerybeast? :P

Answer (score 1):

This is because coulmn for sum of price will not be named price in the $row, it will be sum(price). If you want to be sure of the name, change your SQL with to accomodate an alias to:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS sum_of_price FROM `Fuelconsumption` WHERE `date` like '%09-2012%'
```

and then use it as `$row['sum_of_price']`.

Answer (score -1):

Try change your query to become:

```
SELECT SUM(price) price
FROM `Fuelconsumption` 
WHERE `date` like '%09-2012%'
```

Comment: You should use `AS` to create aliases as far as I know.

Comment: NO, on mysql, you can use implicit alias without supply `as` :)